# query load cases page to go blank on multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Using this code, when i click it more than twice the page goes blank. The source of the page however still stays the same. Does anyone know why?

```
$('.changetopics').click(function (e) {
    $('#loadingAjaxs').show();
    $('#flubeslogo').hide();
    e.preventDefault();

    var link = '@Url.Action("DetailPop", "Topics", new { @id = 1, @name= 2, @forum = "all", @page = 0})';

    link = link.replace(1, $(this).data('id'));
    link = link.replace(2, $(this).data('shortname'));

    var titleid = $(this).data('id');
    var titlename = $(this).data('shortname');
    $('.collapsemain'+$(this).data('id')).load(link, function () {
        $('#loadingAjaxs').hide();
        $('#flubeslogo').show();
        });
});
```

Comment: When you look at Firebug, of course the source of the page will remain the same. What you see on the screen is the current state of the DOM, what you se in "show source code" is what the server returned at that time. If you put a breakpoint on this line: `var titleid =  $(this).data('id')`, do you guarantee that titleid is being populated?

Comment: titleid is always populated.